DragGesture.onChange: for loop overloads CPU and freeze app
I have an app in which you can draw using points, the code presented below is needed so that when one line (already drawn) intersects with current, the current line is deleted.
When I try to do this in DragGesture().onChanged, the CPU is overloaded and the lines are drawn with a delay.
How to fix that?
import SwiftUI
import CoreGraphics

struct Drawing1 {
    var points1: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint]()
}
struct Drawing2 {
    var points2: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint]()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentDrawing1: Drawing1 = Drawing1()
    @State private var drawings1: [Drawing1] = [Drawing1]()
    @State private var currentDrawing2: Drawing2 = Drawing2()
    @State private var drawings2: [Drawing2] = [Drawing2]()
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            
            
                
                    Path { path1 in
                        for drawings1 in self.drawings1 {
                            self.add1(drawings1: drawings1, toPath1: &path1)
                        }
                        self.add1(drawings1: self.currentDrawing1, toPath1: &path1)
                        
                        
                    }
                    .stroke(Color.orange, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                
               
                    Path { path2 in
                        for drawings2 in self.drawings2 {
                            self.add2(drawings2: drawings2, toPath2: &path2)
                        }
                        self.add2(drawings2: self.currentDrawing2, toPath2: &path2)
                        
                    }
                    .stroke(Color.black, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                
            
            Image("example1")
                .resizable( resizingMode: .stretch)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipped()
                .position(x:200, y:200)
                .frame(width: 100, height:100)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value1 in
                            let currentPoint1 = value1.location
                            self.currentDrawing1.points1.append(currentPoint1)
                            
                            
                        }  )
                        .onEnded({ value1 in
                            
                            self.drawings1.append(self.currentDrawing1)
                            self.currentDrawing1 = Drawing1()
                        }
                                )
                    
                )
            
            Image("example2")
                .resizable( resizingMode: .stretch)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipped()
                .position(x:100, y:100)
                .frame(width: 100, height:100)
            
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value2 in
                            let currentPoint2 = value2.location
                            self.currentDrawing2.points2.append(currentPoint2)
                            
                            
                            if drawings1.count > 0
                            {
                                let points2 = currentDrawing2.points2
                                let points1 = drawings1[0].points1
                                if points2.count > 0
                                {
                                    
                                    for i in 0..<points2.count-1 {
                                        let current2 = points2[i]
                                        let next2 = points2[i+1]
                                        for i in 0..<points1.count-1 {
                                            let current = points1[i]
                                            let next = points1[i+1]
                                            
                                            
                                            let delta1x = next.x - current.x
                                            let delta1y = next.y - current.y
                                            let delta2x = next2.x - current2.x
                                            let delta2y = next2.y - current2.y
                                            
                                            // create a 2D matrix from our vectors and calculate the determinant
                                            let determinant = delta1x * delta2y - delta2x * delta1y
                                            
                                            if abs(determinant) < 0.0001 {
                                                // if the determinant is effectively zero then the lines are parallel/colinear
                                                //return nil
                                            }
                                            
                                            // if the coefficients both lie between 0 and 1 then we have an intersection
                                            let ab = ((current.y - current2.y) * delta2x - (current.x - current2.x) * delta2y) / determinant
                                            
                                            if ab > 0 && ab < 1 {
                                                let cd = ((current.y - current2.y) * delta1x - (current.x - current2.x) * delta1y) / determinant
                                                
                                                if cd > 0 && cd < 1 {
                                                    // lines cross
                                                    
                                                    self.currentDrawing2.points2.removeAll()
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                            )
                        .onEnded( { value2 in
                            self.drawings2.append(self.currentDrawing2)
                            self.currentDrawing2 = Drawing2()
                        })
                )
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
        }
    }
    private func add1(drawings1: Drawing1, toPath1 path1: inout Path) {
        let points1 = drawings1.points1
        if points1.count > 1 {
            for i in 0..<points1.count-1 {
                let current = points1[i]
                let next = points1[i+1]
                path1.move(to: current)
                path1.addLine(to: next)
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func add2(drawings2: Drawing2, toPath2 path2: inout Path) {
        let points2 = drawings2.points2
        if points2.count > 1 {
            for i in 0..<points2.count-1 {
                let current = points2[i]
                let next = points2[i+1]
                path2.move(to: current)
                path2.addLine(to: next)
                
            }
            }
        }
}

I tried to implement this in .onEnded. Everything works fine here, but I need it to work in real time.

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish, but I think your code is doing far more work than needed. You question states: "when one line (already drawn) intersects with current, the current line is deleted." ... Is this the general idea? https://i.sstatic.net/KPjrM9rG.png

Thanks for your comment, it's really nice that someone is trying to help. I've been trying to resolve this issue for a week now and have been unsuccessful.  Absolutely right.  If the current line intersects with one already drawn, the current one should be deleted.

We can detect intersecting paths with lineIntersection(_:eoFill:)
For example, let's create two Paths:
var pth1 = Path()
var pth2 = Path()
        
pth1.move(to: .init(x: 200.0, y: 300.0))
pth1.addLine(to: .init(x: 150.0, y: 350.0))
pth1.addLine(to: .init(x: 120.0, y: 320.0))
pth1.addLine(to: .init(x:  80.0, y: 250.0))
        
pth2.move(to: .init(x: 180.0, y: 200.0))
pth2.addLine(to: .init(x: 180.0, y: 240.0))
pth2.addLine(to: .init(x: 140.0, y: 260.0))
pth2.addLine(to: .init(x: 160.0, y: 300.0))
        

If we draw them, it looks like this:

So, let's check:
let iPath = pth1.lineIntersection(pth2)
        
// we need to check the .cgPath
if iPath.cgPath.isEmpty {
    print("Paths do NOT Intersect")
} else {
    print("Paths Intersect!")
}
        

Debug console output will be: Paths do NOT Intersect
If we add another line segment to pth2:
pth2.addLine(to: .init(x: 220.0, y: 340.0))

it now looks like this:

and the output will be: Paths Intersect!
So, instead of tracking all of the points while dragging, let's update a Path:
struct Drawing {
    var thePath: Path = Path()
}

and in .onChanged we can use .move(to:) and .addLine(to:) so we're not re-building the path every cycle.
Let's also define two other properties:
struct Drawing {
    var thePath: Path = Path()
    var theColor: Color = Color.black
    var canDraw: Bool = true
}

It's not clear what you're trying to do with your arrays of "drawings" so we'll simplify things a bit:
@State private var currentDrawing1: Drawing = Drawing(theColor: Color.red)
@State private var currentDrawing2: Drawing = Drawing(theColor: Color.blue)

Here's the full view struct that you can examine and try out (should be enough comments):
struct DrawIntersectView: View {
    @State private var currentDrawing1: Drawing = Drawing(theColor: Color.red)
    @State private var currentDrawing2: Drawing = Drawing(theColor: Color.blue)
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            
            currentDrawing1.thePath
                .stroke(currentDrawing1.theColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            
            currentDrawing2.thePath
                .stroke(currentDrawing2.theColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            
            
            Image("example1")
                .resizable( resizingMode: .stretch)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipped()
                .position(x:200, y:200)
                .frame(width: 100, height:100)
                .opacity(0.5)   // so we can see the line start
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            let currentPoint = value.location
                            // if the path has no points yet, move to
                            // else, addLine to
                            if self.currentDrawing1.thePath.isEmpty {
                                self.currentDrawing1.thePath.move(to: currentPoint)
                            } else {
                                self.currentDrawing1.thePath.addLine(to: currentPoint)
                            }
                            
                        })
                        .onEnded({ value in
                        })
                    
                )
            
            Image("example2")
                .resizable( resizingMode: .stretch)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipped()
                .position(x:100, y:100)
                .frame(width: 100, height:100)
                .opacity(0.5)   // so we can see the line start
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            // if we haven't yet drawn from currentDrawing2
                            //  just return
                            if self.currentDrawing1.thePath.isEmpty {
                                return
                            }
                            
                            // if we've crossed the first line, we don't want to
                            //  draw until the user has lifted the touch (ended the current drag)
                            if !self.currentDrawing2.canDraw {
                                return
                            }
                                
                            let currentPoint = value.location
                            // if the path has no points yet, move to
                            // else, addLine to
                            if self.currentDrawing2.thePath.isEmpty {
                                self.currentDrawing2.thePath.move(to: currentPoint)
                            } else {
                                self.currentDrawing2.thePath.addLine(to: currentPoint)
                            }

                            // get lineIntersection of the paths from drawing 1 and drawing 2
                            let t = self.currentDrawing1.thePath.lineIntersection(self.currentDrawing2.thePath)
                            if !t.cgPath.isEmpty {
                                print("intersects")
                                self.currentDrawing2.canDraw = false
                                self.currentDrawing2.thePath = Path()
                            }
                            
                        })
                        .onEnded({ value in
                            // allow drawing again
                            self.currentDrawing2.canDraw = true
                        })
                )
        }
        
    }
    
}

Worth noting: because you're using a path line width of 10... if we draw the lines / paths like this:

they do NOT intersect! That's because the actual line paths are:


Edit
The above doesn't quite work...
Apple's docs on CGPath Instance Methods (.lineIntersection / .intersection / etc) are rather lacking.
It turns out that .lineIntersection works like this...
Two non-intersecting paths:

"under-the-hood" the paths get closed:

if we fill them:

.intersection gets this path (yellow):

and .lineIntersection returns the portion of the line from that intersection (yellow again):

So that won't work.
To "fix" that, we can use
copy(strokingWithWidth:lineCap:lineJoin:miterLimit:transform:)

So, if we do:
let sp1 = pth1.copy(strokingWithWidth: 10.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 1.0)

on this path:

we get a closed path (fill red):

Now we can generate two "stroked paths" and check for intersection:
let sp1 = self.currentDrawing1.thePath.cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: 10.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 1.0)
let sp2 = self.currentDrawing2.thePath.cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: 10.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 1.0)
if sp1.intersects(sp2)
    print("intersects")
    // remove the 2nd path, etc
}

So, modified example:
struct Drawing {
    var thePath: Path = Path()
    var sPath: CGPath?      // "stroked" path
    var theColor: Color = Color.black
    var canDraw: Bool = true
}

// stroking with intersection -- iOS 16+
struct DrawIntersectView: View {
    @State private var currentDrawing1: Drawing = Drawing(theColor: Color.red)
    @State private var currentDrawing2: Drawing = Drawing(theColor: Color.blue)
    
    private var lineWidth: CGFloat = 10.0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            
            currentDrawing1.thePath
                .stroke(currentDrawing1.theColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: self.lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            
            currentDrawing2.thePath
                .stroke(currentDrawing2.theColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: self.lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            
            
            Image("example1")
                .resizable( resizingMode: .stretch)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipped()
                .position(x:200, y:200)
                .frame(width: 100, height:100)
                .opacity(0.5)   // so we can see the line start
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            let currentPoint = value.location
                            // if the path has no points yet, move to
                            // else, addLine to
                            if self.currentDrawing1.thePath.isEmpty {
                                self.currentDrawing1.thePath.move(to: currentPoint)
                            } else {
                                self.currentDrawing1.thePath.addLine(to: currentPoint)
                            }
                            
                        })
                        .onEnded({ value in
                            self.currentDrawing1.sPath = self.currentDrawing1.thePath.cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: self.lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 1.0)
                        })
                    
                )
            
            Image("example2")
                .resizable( resizingMode: .stretch)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipped()
                .position(x:100, y:100)
                .frame(width: 100, height:100)
                .opacity(0.5)   // so we can see the line start
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            // if we haven't yet drawn from currentDrawing2
                            //  just return
                            if self.currentDrawing1.thePath.isEmpty {
                                return
                            }
                            
                            // if we've crossed the first line, we don't want to
                            //  draw until the user has lifted the touch (ended the current drag)
                            if !self.currentDrawing2.canDraw {
                                return
                            }
                            
                            let currentPoint = value.location
                            // if the path has no points yet, move to
                            // else, addLine to
                            if self.currentDrawing2.thePath.isEmpty {
                                self.currentDrawing2.thePath.move(to: currentPoint)
                            } else {
                                self.currentDrawing2.thePath.addLine(to: currentPoint)
                            }
                            
                            self.currentDrawing2.sPath = self.currentDrawing2.thePath.cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: self.lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 1.0)
                            if let sp1 = self.currentDrawing1.sPath, let sp2 = self.currentDrawing2.sPath {
                                if sp1.intersects(sp2) {
                                    print("intersects")
                                    self.currentDrawing2.canDraw = false
                                    self.currentDrawing2.thePath = Path()
                                }
                            }
                            
                        })
                        .onEnded({ value in
                            // allow drawing again
                            self.currentDrawing2.canDraw = true
                        })
                )
        }
        
    }
    
}


Edit 2 - comment: "must work with iOS 14"
Unfortunately, .intersects() is an iOS 16+ method...
To be iOS 14 compatible, we can still use the "stroked path" approach for "line 1" and then check .contains for each new point:
// does currentDrawing1's stroked path contain the current point?
if let sp = currentDrawing1.sPath, sp.contains(currentPoint) {
    print("intersects")
    self.currentDrawing2.canDraw = false
    self.currentDrawing2.thePath = Path()
}

// stroking with contains -- iOS 14
struct DrawIntersectView: View {
    @State private var currentDrawing1: Drawing = Drawing(theColor: Color.red)
    @State private var currentDrawing2: Drawing = Drawing(theColor: Color.blue)
    
    private var lineWidth: CGFloat = 10.0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            
            currentDrawing1.thePath
                .stroke(currentDrawing1.theColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: self.lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            
            currentDrawing2.thePath
                .stroke(currentDrawing2.theColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: self.lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            
            
            Image("example1")
                .resizable( resizingMode: .stretch)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipped()
                .position(x:200, y:200)
                .frame(width: 100, height:100)
                .opacity(0.5)   // so we can see the line start
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            let currentPoint = value.location
                            // if the path has no points yet, move to
                            // else, addLine to
                            if self.currentDrawing1.thePath.isEmpty {
                                self.currentDrawing1.thePath.move(to: currentPoint)
                            } else {
                                self.currentDrawing1.thePath.addLine(to: currentPoint)
                            }
                            
                        })
                        .onEnded({ value in
                            // update currentDrawing1's "stroked path"
                            self.currentDrawing1.sPath = self.currentDrawing1.thePath.cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: self.lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 1.0)
                        })
                    
                )
            
            Image("example2")
                .resizable( resizingMode: .stretch)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipped()
                .position(x:100, y:100)
                .frame(width: 100, height:100)
                .opacity(0.5)   // so we can see the line start
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            // if we haven't yet drawn from currentDrawing2
                            //  just return
                            if self.currentDrawing1.thePath.isEmpty {
                                return
                            }
                            
                            // if we've crossed the first line, we don't want to
                            //  draw until the user has lifted the touch (ended the current drag)
                            if !self.currentDrawing2.canDraw {
                                return
                            }
                            
                            let currentPoint = value.location
                            // if the path has no points yet, move to
                            // else, addLine to
                            if self.currentDrawing2.thePath.isEmpty {
                                self.currentDrawing2.thePath.move(to: currentPoint)
                            } else {
                                self.currentDrawing2.thePath.addLine(to: currentPoint)
                            }
                            
                            // does currentDrawing1's stroked path contain the current point?
                            if let sp = currentDrawing1.sPath, sp.contains(currentPoint) {
                                print("intersects")
                                self.currentDrawing2.canDraw = false
                                self.currentDrawing2.thePath = Path()
                            }
                            
                        })
                        .onEnded({ value in
                            // allow drawing again
                            self.currentDrawing2.canDraw = true
                        })
                )
        }
        
    }
    
}

Still have one more thing to deal with...
When dragging quickly, it's pretty easy to get a distance greater-than 10-points between the previous point and the current point:

None of those points is inside the red stroked-path.
To "fix" that...
Approach 1:

in .onChanged()

if the distance from the previous point to the current point is greater-than 9 (to be on the safe side)
calculate the points on the line from prev to current, every 8-points
check each of those with .contains



Approach 2 (if Approach 1 induces lag, which it probably won't):

in .onEnded()

check if .canDraw is still true
if so, either use your current line-compare code, or
step through line2's points, and do the "every 8-points distance" between any consecutive points with greater-than 9=point distance



Pretty easy to find a "points on line with spacing" function out there.

Edit 3
Here is the iOS 14 version, that also handles very-quick-drag:
// stroking with contains and gap handling -- iOS 14

Edit 4 - fixed the "points on line" interpolation
struct Drawing {
    var points: [CGPoint] = []
    var thePath: Path = Path()
    var sPath: CGPath?      // "stroked" path
    var theColor: Color = Color.black
    var canDraw: Bool = true
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentDrawing1: Drawing = Drawing(theColor: Color.red)
    @State private var currentDrawing2: Drawing = Drawing(theColor: Color.blue)
    
    private var lineWidth: CGFloat = 10.0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            
            currentDrawing1.thePath
                .stroke(currentDrawing1.theColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: self.lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            
            currentDrawing2.thePath
                .stroke(currentDrawing2.theColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: self.lineWidth, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            
            Image("example1")
                .resizable( resizingMode: .stretch)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipped()
                .position(x:200, y:200)
                .frame(width: 100, height:100)
                .opacity(0.5)   // so we can see the line start
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            let currentPoint = value.location
                            self.currentDrawing1.points.append(currentPoint)
                            // if the path has no points yet, move to
                            // else, addLine to
                            if self.currentDrawing1.thePath.isEmpty {
                                self.currentDrawing1.thePath.move(to: currentPoint)
                            } else {
                                self.currentDrawing1.thePath.addLine(to: currentPoint)
                            }
                            
                        })
                        .onEnded({ value in
                            // update currentDrawing1's "stroked path"
                            //  stroke with lineWidth * 2.0 so we get edge-to-edge detection
                            self.currentDrawing1.sPath = self.currentDrawing1.thePath.cgPath.copy(strokingWithWidth: self.lineWidth * 2.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: 1.0)
                        })
                    
                )
            
            Image("example2")
                .resizable( resizingMode: .stretch)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipped()
                .position(x:100, y:100)
                .frame(width: 100, height:100)
                .opacity(0.5)   // so we can see the line start
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            // if we haven't yet drawn from currentDrawing2
                            //  just return
                            if self.currentDrawing1.thePath.isEmpty {
                                return
                            }
                            
                            // if we've crossed the first line, we don't want to
                            //  draw until the user has lifted the touch (ended the current drag)
                            if !self.currentDrawing2.canDraw {
                                return
                            }
                            
                            let currentPoint = value.location
                            self.currentDrawing2.points.append(currentPoint)

                            // get the previous point
                            let prevPoint = self.currentDrawing2.thePath.currentPoint
                            
                            // if the path has no points yet, move to
                            // else, addLine to
                            if self.currentDrawing2.thePath.isEmpty {
                                self.currentDrawing2.thePath.move(to: currentPoint)
                            } else {
                                self.currentDrawing2.thePath.addLine(to: currentPoint)
                            }
                            
                            // does currentDrawing1's stroked path contain the current point?
                            if let sp = currentDrawing1.sPath, sp.contains(currentPoint) {
                                print("intersects")
                                self.currentDrawing2.canDraw = false
                                self.currentDrawing2.thePath = Path()
                            } else {
                                // do we have a previous point?
                                if let pp = prevPoint {
                                    // get the distance from previous to current
                                    let deltaX = pp.x - currentPoint.x
                                    let deltaY = pp.y - currentPoint.y
                                    let length = hypot(deltaX, deltaY)
                                    // if it's greater-than 9.0
                                    if length > 9.0 {
                                        // get the array of points between previous and current, each 8-points apart
                                        let pts = pointsOnLine(start: pp, end: currentPoint)
                                        for p in pts {
                                            // does currentDrawing1's stroked path contain the one of the calculated points?
                                            if let sp = currentDrawing1.sPath, sp.contains(p) {
                                                print("points on line intersects")
                                                self.currentDrawing2.canDraw = false
                                                self.currentDrawing2.thePath = Path()
                                                break
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .onEnded({ value in
                            // allow drawing again
                            self.currentDrawing2.canDraw = true
                        })
                )
        }
        
    }
    
    func pointsOnLine(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint, spacing: CGFloat = 8.0) -> [CGPoint] {
        var points: [CGPoint] = []
        
        // Calculate the differences in x and y
        let deltaX = end.x - start.x
        let deltaY = end.y - start.y
        
        // Calculate the length of the line
        let length = hypot(deltaX, deltaY)
        
        // Normalize the direction of the line to unit length
        let unitX = deltaX / length
        let unitY = deltaY / length
        
        // Add the first point (start point)
        points.append(start)
        
        // Add points at every spacing distance along the line
        var currentDistance: CGFloat = spacing
        while currentDistance < length {
            let x = start.x + unitX * currentDistance
            let y = start.y + unitY * currentDistance
            points.append(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            currentDistance += spacing
        }
        
        // Add the last point (end point)
        points.append(end)
        
        return points
    }
    
}


Edit 5 - see if this makes sense...
Animated GIF - open this image in a new tab/window if the animation is not running...

Here is your code (with your most recent edits), modified to use interpolated points:
struct Drawing1 {
    var points1: [CGPoint] = []
}
struct Drawing2 {
    var points2: [CGPoint] = []
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentDrawing1: Drawing1 = Drawing1()
    @State private var drawings1: [Drawing1] = [Drawing1]()
    @State private var currentDrawing2: Drawing2 = Drawing2()
    @State private var drawings2: [Drawing2] = [Drawing2]()
    @State private var check: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            
            Path { path1 in
                for drawings1 in self.drawings1 {
                    self.add1(drawings1: drawings1, toPath1: &path1)
                }
                self.add1(drawings1: self.currentDrawing1, toPath1: &path1)
            }
            .stroke(Color.orange, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            
            
            Path { path2 in
                for drawings2 in self.drawings2 {
                    self.add2(drawings2: drawings2, toPath2: &path2)
                }
                self.add2(drawings2: self.currentDrawing2, toPath2: &path2)
                
            }
            .stroke(Color.black, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 10, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            
            Image("example1")
                .resizable( resizingMode: .stretch)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipped()
                .position(x:200, y:200)
                .frame(width: 100, height:100)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value1 in
                            let currentPoint1 = value1.location
                            self.currentDrawing1.points1.append(currentPoint1)
                        })
                        .onEnded({ value1 in
                            // the user has stopped drawing line 1
                            //  generate a new Points array with interpolated points to fill any "gaps"
                            var iPts: [CGPoint] = []
                            iPts.append(self.currentDrawing1.points1[0])
                            for i in 1..<self.currentDrawing1.points1.count {
                                let p1 = self.currentDrawing1.points1[i-1]
                                let p2 = self.currentDrawing1.points1[i]
                                //  default spacing is 8.0, but it can be adjusted if desired
                                let intPoints = pointsOnLine(start: p1, end: p2, spacing: 8.0)
                                iPts.append(contentsOf: intPoints[1...])
                            }
                            // update with interpolated points array
                            self.currentDrawing1.points1 = iPts
                            
                            self.drawings1.append(self.currentDrawing1)
                            self.currentDrawing1 = Drawing1()
                        })
                    
                )
            
            Image("example2")
                .resizable( resizingMode: .stretch)
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipped()
                .position(x:100, y:100)
                .frame(width: 100, height:100)
            
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value2 in
                            if check == false {
                                
                                let currentPoint2 = value2.location
                                
                                if self.currentDrawing2.points2.count == 0
                                {
                                    // this is the first point triggered by the drag gesture
                                    //  so we don't need to compare it to anything
                                    // just append current point to array
                                    self.currentDrawing2.points2.append(currentPoint2)
                                    return()
                                }
                                
                                if drawings1.count > 0
                                {
                                    // get the previous point from the current drag
                                    //  we can "!" force-unwrap it, because we know it exists
                                    let prevPoint = self.currentDrawing2.points2.last!
                                    
                                    // generate an array of interpolated points between last and current
                                    //  default spacing is 8.0, but it can be adjusted if desired
                                    let iPoints = pointsOnLine(start: prevPoint, end: currentPoint2, spacing: 8.0)
                                    
                                    // append the interpolated points to the array
                                    self.currentDrawing2.points2.append(contentsOf: iPoints[1...])
                                    
                                    // loop through those points, hit-testing for a rectangle surrounding each point in drawings1[0].points1
                                    //  we can skip the first point, because it was hit-tested on the previous .onChange() event
                                    for newPoint in iPoints[1...]
                                    {
                                        for pt in drawings1[0].points1
                                        {
                                            if ((pt.x + 9 >= newPoint.x && pt.x - 9 <= newPoint.x)) && ((pt.y + 9 >= newPoint.y) && (pt.y - 9 <= newPoint.y))
                                            {
                                                self.currentDrawing2.points2.removeAll()
                                                check = true
                                                // we hit a "boxed point" so we don't need to check any other points
                                                break
                                            }
                                        }
                                        // if we've hit a "boxed point" we don't need to check the rest of the interpolated points
                                        if check == true { break }
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }
                        })
                        .onEnded( { value2 in
                            // if check is true, that means we intersected the line, so
                            //  only execute this if we have NOT hit the line
                            if !check {
                                self.drawings2.append(self.currentDrawing2)
                                self.currentDrawing2 = Drawing2()
                            }
                            check = false
                        })
                )

        }
    }
    
    private func add1(drawings1: Drawing1, toPath1 path1: inout Path) {
        let points1 = drawings1.points1
        if points1.count > 1 {
            path1.move(to: points1[0])
            for pt in points1[1...] {
                path1.addLine(to: pt)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func add2(drawings2: Drawing2, toPath2 path2: inout Path) {
        let points2 = drawings2.points2
        if points2.count > 1 {
            path2.move(to: points2[0])
            for pt in points2[1...] {
                path2.addLine(to: pt)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func pointsOnLine(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint, spacing: CGFloat = 8.0) -> [CGPoint] {
        var points: [CGPoint] = []
        
        // Calculate the differences in x and y
        let deltaX = end.x - start.x
        let deltaY = end.y - start.y
        
        // Calculate the length of the line
        let length = hypot(deltaX, deltaY)
        
        // Normalize the direction of the line to unit length
        let unitX = deltaX / length
        let unitY = deltaY / length
        
        // Add the first point (start point)
        points.append(start)
        
        // Add points at every spacing distance along the line
        var currentDistance: CGFloat = spacing
        while currentDistance < length {
            let x = start.x + unitX * currentDistance
            let y = start.y + unitY * currentDistance
            points.append(CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
            currentDistance += spacing
        }
        
        // Add the last point (end point)
        points.append(end)
        
        return points
    }
    
}


Thanks for such an extensive answer. Your code works if the line is crossed on the left side, if you try to cross it on the right, then it is deleted much earlier than the current one reaches it. Also, depending on the complexity of the line, in some areas it is removed earlier https://i.sstatic.net/TpWiKvVJ.gif. Also I need to save functions and arrays for further calculations of the number of lines drawn.
Anyway lineIntersection(_:eoFill:) requires using ios 17, my project works since ios 14. Thanks a lot, but I can't use this code :(

@264 - yeah, I was playing with it a bit more and discovered an unexpected behavior (line deleted early). I will edit my question and post a fix ... as well as another approach that may be suitable (will work with iOS 14 [and earlier]).

@264 - see the (long) Edit to my answer.

Finally, you are faced with the problem of why I even started writing the code from the question. I have a much simpler code for removing lines https://i.sstatic.net/65nlHgvB.png, but the biggest problem was that it skips points if the gesture is too fast.
The function to find intermediate points is the solution.
The only question I have is, can I implement this function inside my drawing function? I'm trying to do this but I still don't understand how to implement it

@264 - you may think that is "much simpler code" ... but if I've drawn this line from "1": https://i.sstatic.net/nt3FyJPN.png ... when I draw from "2" your code is looping through 1,200 points for every .onChanged() event. Also, you would need to fill-in the "gap points" for both lines. I don't know what your actual goal is, but it sure seems like using a stroked path would be much more efficient.

Your code is perfect. Unfortunately, I can't rewrite all the code under stroked path because there is a lot of data connected to this code. For now I can only use the "simple code". Maybe in the future I will rewrite it. Thanks for the last edit, now I can use the code in my function. https://i.sstatic.net/OlyUHn41.png And based on the data in the console, everything works correctly, but for some reason the points from points2 do not go to another array (drawings2).  Is it possible to add the points from points2 to the drawings2 array for further comparison using “simple code”?

@264 - if you can post your current (runnable) code, I'll see if I can give you a "simple code" solution.

edited my question

@264 - what you're doing with multiple "drawings" is rather confusing... You said you need to "save arrays for further calculations" ... do you need to save the actual points? Or, can you work with saving the interpolation? https://i.sstatic.net/Wxr9H0hw.png

Not necessarily actual. I can work with the saving interpolations.

@264 - OK ... I'll post more code tomorrow morning.

@264 - See Edit 5 ... It's still not clear to me what your goal is with multiple "drawings" but hopefully this will get you on your way.

IT WORKS!
You are the hero of my life and a brilliant person. I admire your knowledge, talent and your enthusiasm. God bless you for entire of your life!
